# Dispatch inside action is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this authActions.js file:

```
export function setCurrentUser(user) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_USER,
        user
    }
}

export function login(loginData) {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch('/api/user/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: loginData,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            let token = data;
            localStorage.setItem("token", token);
            dispatch(setCurrentUser)(token);
        });

    }
}
```

and it is telling me dispatch(setCurrentUser)(token); is not a function. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

EDIT:

Now my reducer is not applying a value.

```
const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated : false,
    user : { "Name" : "rz" }
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_USER:
            console.log(action.payload);
            return {
                isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
                user: action.payload
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

The payload has the data but it's never overwriting the initial state.

Comment: Did you mean `dispatch(setCurrentUser(token));`? (note the placement of the parentheses)

Comment: @NicholasTower that works however now my user in my state is always be set to undefined.

Comment: @KevinZ. did you check `token` value?Is it coming correct?

Comment: @KevinZ. to help diagnose that we'll need to see your reducer

Comment: @NicholasTower I edited the post

Comment: setCurrentUser creates an action object with a `user` property, but then your reducer tries to use a nonexistent `payload` property. You'll need to update one or the other so that they're using the same variable name.